# Python why is 'int' object is not iterable in a simple if, else loop function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I alreay have a working solution for the code below but can you please help me understand why python says "'int" object is not iterable" when I run this code.

And the simplest way to fixing this without changing my whole code. Thank you.

```
    def test(n):
        for i in n:
            if i < 0:
                return 'negative'
            if i == 0:
                return 'zero'
            else:
                return 'positive'
```

Comment: Is n an int? If so, the problem can't be made much more clearer than what the error message says. ints are not iterable. You need an iterable of some sort (like a list, or set, or dict) in order to iterate.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Test a range of integers, test a single integer or test every digit in an integer?

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to test a single positive or negative int. going to use if and elif and not the for loop. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(n):
       if i < 0:
           return 'negative'
```

Simple.

To answer your question about why `int` isn't iterable, int is just a value type. To iterate over something you need a "collection" like a list, array, dictionary, or whatever else that you can run through a loop.

`range(n)` simply returns a list of numbers from 0 to whatever you pass in as `n`.

*edit*

As Cyber pointed out, a `for` loop is not what you want here. But, if you want a for loop in a different situation, this is the way to do it.

Comment: when i do test(-3) it doesn't return anything

Comment: You can't iterate over a negative starting place for a range. Iteration is really not what you want to do here to be honest, but I really wasn't sure if that's what you wanted to do, so I answered as close to what you were asking as possible. 

If you're just testing the values then you'll want a solution like @Cyber presented, which means a `for` loop iterating over a value is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: ok got it, so for loop with range to iterate of positive number or just drop the for loop altogether and go with if and elif. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to write a loop then use `range`. If you want to just see whether a value is zero, positive or negative, then use if, elif, else.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a for loop

```
def test(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 'negative'
    elif n == 0:
        return 'zero'
    else:
        return 'positive'
```

Comment: Oh jeez, my mistake that was dumb